# Mysql event:Run at specific intervals during a specific period

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I am reading an article on sitepoint - http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/  on the subject of mysql events and i came across this point when you can schedule

And i quote

> Run at specific intervals during a specific period: EVERY n
>   [HOUR|MONTH|WEEK|DAY|MINUTE] STARTS date ENDS date e.g. EVERY 1 DAY
>   STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 WEEK ENDS ’2012-01-01 00:00.00′

I am having a hard time understanding what the author means.Can anyone help me out?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author is just giving an example, how a statement might be built up to create an event that starts and runs at some point regularly.

```
EVERY n /*give here a number*/
[HOUR|MONTH|WEEK|DAY|MINUTE] /*choose here one of those values*/
STARTS date /*name a date here...*/
ENDS date /*...and here*/
```

The author also supplies an example:

```
EVERY 1 DAY 
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 WEEK 
ENDS '2012-01-01 00:00.00'
```

In the example the query that is specified in the event is executed every day at the same time the event is created but one week later and ends at 2012-01-01.

Here's the official manual page with a lot more examples. [13.1.11 CREATE EVENT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)

I personally find the official manual the best to learn about MySQL. It's very well written. Give it a try :)